# How to use two sys.any in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new to dialogflow. I'm trying to get "comments" and "notes" from the user. For these kind of parameters, I'm using "@sys.any" entity. without mixing the value of comments and notes, how to use two "@sys.any" entity in dialogflow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can assign a [parameter name](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters#parameter_name) to an entity and thereby distinguish between entities of the same type. The parameter name is usually given behind the colon in a entity reference, i.e. you could have a `@sys.any:comment` and `@sys.any:note` in the same intent.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-design                                       
Do not define entities that match virtually anything. This degrades the performance and quality of ML. Nearly everything in every training phrase will be evaluated as a possible match. Consider using "@sys.any" instead. Similarly, composite entities should not contain a single "@sys.any" as a synonym.